# How to check install conditions for prerequisites with msi package in WIX 3.6

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.6, prerequisites

I'm trying to combine my package in a single setup exe file and upload it to internet.

I have used a WIX bootstrapper (BURN) that contains project msi output, and pre-requisite .net framework 2.0, windows installer 3.1 , visual c++ 2005 redistributables, and microsoft report viewer. I have used WIX 3.6 in Visual studio 2008.

I have attached the msi file and prerequisites in the bootstrapper using following commands.

```
<ExePackage SourceFile ="ReportViewer\ReportViewer.exe" Compressed ="yes" Vital ="no" Permanent = "yes" />
<ExePackage SourceFile ="vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe" Compressed ="yes" Vital ="no" Permanent ="yes"/>
<ExePackage SourceFile ="WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe" Compressed ="yes" Vital ="no" Permanent ="yes"/>     
<MsiPackage SourceFile ="myproject.msi" Compressed ="yes" ForcePerMachine ="yes"/>
```

Now the bootstrapper will compress all pre-requisites in a single exe.

Now i need to install the pre-requisites only when it is not exists already ?

How to write this install condition in the above. I have checked InstallCommand option but don't know how to use it ? Any code snippets for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set values for the [ExePackage/@DetectCondition](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_exepackage.htm) attribute. For what it should be for a particular package, consult the documentation for the package. You'll probably need [Bundle/RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_registrysearch.htm) elements to [set bundle variables](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/bundle_define_searches.htm) for the conditions.

As a cross-reference, you can look at the XML files for any corresponding Visual Studio Bootstrapper package, typically at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SDK\v2.0\Bootstrapper` or similar.